# Como utilizar o DOMPDF no Laravel 4 em conjunto com uma view em BLADE?

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel, pdf

Preciso gerar relatório em PDF no Laravel 4. Encontrei várias alternativas e estou em dúvida sobre qual melhor opção:

- [DOMPDF](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) ([link alternativo](https://github.com/thujohn/pdf-l4))
  Parece muito fácil de utilizar, uma vez que é o nosso bom e velho HTML mais CSS, porém não entendi como vou fazer o cabeçalho/rodapé e a quebra de página.
- [FPDF](https://github.com/xroot/laravel-fpdf)
  Conheço há algum tempo, porém tem que escrever bastante para conseguir gerar o PDF.
- [TCPDF](https://github.com/markvdputten/tcpdf)
  Não conheço nada desta versão.

Pergunta: como utilizar o DOMPDF/Laravel para renderizar uma view pelo BLADE? Ou seria mais simples usar uma das outras duas bibliotecas acima?

Comment: Bem-vindo helderam. Tem uma forma de você editar sua pergunta para torná-la mais adequada para um site de Q&A? Precisamos de perguntas que gerem respostas objetivas. Não somos um fórum de discussão sobre um assunto. O tema não é problema, mas pelas informações fornecidas as respostas acabarão sendo opiniões. Eu acho que dá para salvar a questão se conseguir objetividade no que você precisa.

Comment: Como não foi uma dúvida e sim uma discussão: Minha sugestão é:   

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy

Comment: Obrigado pelas recomendações. Procurei ajustar para ficar conforme as regras. Por favor se ainda não ficou bom, me avise que tentarei melhorar mais ok ?.

Comment: Pessoal, estudei bastante e escolhi ficar com o FPDF mesmo que já conhecia. Da um pouco mais de trabalho mas fica perfeito o resultado e voce tem o controle TOTAL E FINO sobre o PDF gerado. Obrigado a atenção de todos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helderam, o Package do FPDF na verdade é a Facade que disponibiliza o FPDF dentro da aplicação Laravel 4.

Os cabeçalhos e rodapé podem ser configurados usando-se os mesmos métodos do FPDF sozinho.

Te recomendo brincar um pouco com a documentação de cada Biblioteca (não a documentação do Pacote) e ver em qual você fica mais confortável